# hi guys please help me with the script problem below on the $ stock variable

Tags: php

[A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: stok

Filename: controllers/Barangkeluar.php

Line Number: 29

---

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv9ru.png)

hi friends please help me on the script below

Comment: please click number 1 to see a picture, a problem with my script

Comment: Please always add your code as text, not as an image of code. It makes it extremely hard to troubleshoot.